# openSUSE: "Permission denied" error on Cron log file

Tags: linux, permissions, cron, logs, opensuse

using: openSUSE Leap 42.2

/etc/cron.d/mysite file content:

```
* * * * * wwwrun /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite/cron.php >> /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron 2>&1
```

/etc/cron.d/ dir content:

```
/etc/cron.d # ls -ls
total 12
4 -rw------- 1 root root 142 May  7  2018 autologout
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 289 Jan  8 14:33 mysite
4 -rw------- 1 root root 369 May  7  2018 seccheck
```

mail message:

```
Message 103:
From wwwrun@linux.suse  Wed Jan  8 18:52:01 2020
X-Original-To: wwwrun
Delivered-To: wwwrun@linux.suse
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <wwwrun@linux.suse>
To: wwwrun@linux.suse
Subject: Cron <wwwrun@mysite1> /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite/cron.php >> /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron 2>&1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=312343>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/11>
X-Cron-Env: <LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/lib/wwwrun>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=wwwrun>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=wwwrun>
Date: Wed,  8 Jan 2020 18:52:01 +0100 (CET)

/bin/sh: /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron: Permission denied
```

mysite.cron log file

```
ls -la /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron
-rw-rw-rw- 1 wwwrun www 953 Jan  8 14:08 /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron
```

How to fix this?

Executing

```
/usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite/cron.php >> /var/log/apache2/mysite.cron 2>&1
```

from terminal as root, executes well, without permission error.

Comment: I don't have a SUSE instance handy, but I wonder if SELinux is enabled & enforcing?

Comment: selinux policy is not installed

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution is available here:
https://serverfault.com/a/998176/302842

Thanks to Cameron Kerr (@cameron-kerr)!